# Flex Mobile -- where is s:ViewNavigatorApplication?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I have Flex Hero running in Burrito Build 17689 to explore mobile iOS/Android development.
Have read that `s:MobileApplication` and `s:TabbedMobileApplication` have been changed to `s:ViewNavigatorApplication` and `s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication` respectively.
I downloaded AIR 2.6, did a folder merge with Hero SDK but cannot see these applications in mobilecomponents.swc (which wasn't part of Air SDK 2.6) when I browse in Flash Builder.

Is there any way to develop with these new components?

Comment: Where have you read that?  I believe it's still MobileApplication and within that you can use the ViewNavigator with specific views.

Comment: Read about it here http://riarockstars.com/2011/03/22/transitioning-from-air-2-5-to-2-6/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter .

Comment: I want to use the newer version so I can have my tabs at the bottom of the app. And have a nicer-looking actionBar without skinning everything myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no public releases (that I know of) of the Flex Hero SDK that support `ViewNavigatorApplication` yet.  The only public SDK available for mobile is the one that was released at MAX and it still uses `MobileApplication`.  There are other "Flex Hero" SDKs available to download since then, but they don't include the mobile stuff yet: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+Hero

I think that article you referred to is more of a "what to look forward to" article based on the Air 2.6 release that came out.

Answer (score 0):

MobileApplication has indeed been renamed to ViewNavigatorApplication.

The only publicly available build of the full Hero SDK (with mobile features) is the "Preview Release" from MAX 2010.  If you would like to get access to the latest builds (under NDA) you can apply for the pre-release program here: http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2011/02/flex-sdk-and-flash-builder-pre-release-program.html